# Robot Framework pip install into different directory

Tags: pip, robotframework

We are trying to install robotframework into a different directory because of access issue for native python36's site-packages(work place red tapes). I was able to do pip install using the following command:

```
pip install robotframework --target C:\work
```

Although it is displaying the successful installation,  I am missing the .exe files (robot, rebot). I understand if I were to install in the native python site packages, these .exe files gets added to the Scripts folder. But with the target folder specified, how can I make them install under the same target folder?

Comment: There are no exe files. The commands you refer to are bat (windows) or sh (*nix) files and should be found in your `x://python/Scripts` folder.

Comment: version 3.1a1 has .exe files for robot & rebot. But that should not matter whether it is .bat or something else.  Our problem is that if we choose to install robotframework in a different location , these files are not getting installed. Rest of the installation is fine under C:\work.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to install outside of native python site-packages folder using the command:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively to @mac, you may use virtual env to create your python environment outside of limited access paths and install all requirements there.

later on, if you need to use that python venv, either activate it in console or use directly python.exe from inside to call installed packages:

```
<path to venv>/bin/python -m robot.run <rest of attributes>
```